# Does kirtana of lord's name erase the yet-unmanifested effects of sanchita karma?

Tags: karma

that which is manifested and is running is called prarabdha and it cannot be changed so it is said 
but that which is to be manifested in future lives can be changed by meditation on  gods name ? one can avoid all that suffering

Comment: No. Japa & Kirtan are just for concentration, nothing else. God won't help you, you will have to strive by yourself. You have accumulated Karmas, only you are supposed to eradicate. It is **Do by yourself thing**.

Comment: Instead of chanting God's name, Be aware of your day to day activities like eating, bathing etc. Being aware of your daily activities will help you to exhaust your Karmic debts.

Answer (score 1):

short answer - No japa cannot compensate for your deeds.

Long answer - japa/kirtan is only one of the way to start your journey on aadhyatm. It is means to start change flux of thoughts going through mind. To train mind and body to sit and try experiencing "Ras" in god's name and good deeds. This will ultimately start changing your daily habits and interaction group. Once mind starts to extract "sukha/joy" from lord's name, your source of joy is changed from world to god; new path/doors will open. Even if some worldly/physical "dukh/sorrow" comes, they wont effect person much.

That said, it should not be under estimated. It is first step and most critical step in journey from human to super human.

Comment: You should references or citations for your answer. Unsourced answers will be deleted after some weeks.